# Vue: Hide view components conditionally based on URL

Tags: vue.js

My App.vue contains below content:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <core-toolbar />
    <core-drawer />
    <core-view />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

But I want to hide `<core-toolbar />` and `<core-drawer />` when it is routed to `login` page. I am planning to use `v-if` to hide them. But how can I check whether the current route is `login`?

Comment: If you're using `vue-router`, the app component (`v-app` in this case) should contain a `router-view`. Updating the route causes `vue-router` to render a specific view component into the `router-view` (e.g., it renders a `LoginView` component for the `/login` route). You could just omit the `core-toolbar` and `core-drawer` components from `LoginView` instead of using `v-if`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes - If you used `vue-router`, you can use the `$route` object to verify current URL.

You can log the `route` object and verify.

I add name to routes so

```
computed: {
  isLogin() {
     return this.$route.name === 'Login'
  }
}
```

and

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <core-toolbar v-if="isLogin"/>
    <core-drawer v-if="isLogin"/>
    <core-view />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

You can get many more `values` like `queries` / `params` -

Read more here [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `$route.name`

```
<core-toolbar v-show="$route.name!=='login'" />
<core-drawer v-show="$route.name!=='login'" />
```

Comment: `v-show` is like `display: none/block`, if user is on `login` page can view components just by toggling in `dev-tools`

Comment: @SatyamPathak : You are absolutely right, but there will be no harm of data. which is protected from server end. so its okay to load first and then after login it will display fast with after getting data from server.

Comment: I am not convinced with this approach as 1 -  Browser will anyhow re-paint the page as user will be redirected to different page. 2 -Methods related to hidden module will no longer encapsulated and can be triggered which probably throw errors.

Comment: @SatyamPathak: you are again right I respect your thought, but I still think it is not necessary In this situation to display `menu items`. Also OP says two contradict sentence  `I want to hide <core-toolbar /> and <core-drawer />` and `I am planning to use v-if to hide them`. All ideal things not goes as ideal, but it should be. In Programming we can do one things in unlimited ways, it depends how our ultimate goal is. did you read tony19's comment above with question.

Comment: Yes, I did and that's why I re-edited the question for future references.

Answer (score 5):

You can access your route data from your Vue instance

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <core-toolbar />
    <core-drawer v-if="!isLogin" />
    <core-view v-if="!isLogin"/>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        isLogin() {
            return this.$route.name == 'login'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Inspect the object this.$route to get the right params you need.

Comment: Never heard about `f-if` !! It's probably - `v-if`

Answer (score 2):

You can name the routes with an id:

```
const routes = [
  {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login’,
      component: 'login'
  },
];
```

Then you can access `this.$route` whenever to get information about the current route, even in `v-if`:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
      <core-toolbar  v-if="$route.name != 'login'" />
      <core-drawer  v-if="$route.name != 'login'" />
      <core-view />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: You don't need `this` in `html` section

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript to get the path

```
isLoginPage(){
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
if(path == 'login'){
  return true
 }
return false
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use the pathname. What if OP is using the hash mode for the router in production? Then your `path` variable is going to be '#'.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference in Vue3 you need to do the following

```
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import {computed} from "vue";
```

Then:

```
const router= userRouter()
const isLogin= computed(()=>router.name==="Login")
```

Comment: `router.name` points to the name in your routes. Use `const route = useRoute();` and `route.path === "/login"` to match the url path.